# base.html only showing the context data in the home page

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I have a ListView for my homepage that displays extra data using the get_context_data method.
It works, but only in the url of the HomeView, the homepage, not in other templates after I extend the base.html file.
Everything else in base appears, the only thing that doesn't is the context data.

HomeView

```
class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Product
    context_object_name='products'
    template_name = 'main/home.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        news = News.objects.all()
        ...
        context.update({
            'news' : news,
            ...
        })
        
        return context
```

base.html

```
{% load static %}
<body>
    <div class="navbar">
        <a id="title" href="{% url 'home' %}">home</a>
    </div>

    ...

    <div class="side-bar">
        <div class="article">
            <h3>News</h3>
            {% for new in news %}
                <p>{{ new.title }}</p>
            {% endfor %}
            <a href="{% url 'news' %}"><p>See more</p></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}

    ...

</body>
```

home.html

```
{% extends 'main/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div>
    {% for product in products %}
        <p>Some text..</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Does this mean that I have to add a get_context_data method to every single view I have? Isn't that too repetitive and hard to change?

Comment: Other than the answer by @FrançoisConstant, you could subclass `ListView` with a defined `get_context_data()` and inherit that in your views instead of `ListView`, in my opinion this provides simple universal code as needed

Comment: How can I subclass the ListView?

Answer (score 0):

> Does this mean that I have to add a get_context_data method to every single view I have?

No, you don't have to do that. `HomeView.get_context_data(...)` is specific to the home page.

In your example, it looks like you want to show the news in all pages (all pages that use the `base.html` template). In that case, I would recommend to use a `templatetag` to load the news.

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/custom-template-tags/

---

You would do something like:

**my_app/templatetags/news_tags.py**

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('includes/latest_news.html')
def latest_news(context):
    return {
        'news': News.objects.order_by("-published_at")[0:25],
    }
```

**base.html**:

```
{% load static %}
{% load news_tags %}

<body>
    <div class="navbar">
        <a id="title" href="{% url 'home' %}">home</a>
    </div>

    ...

    <div class="side-bar">
        {% latest_news %}
    </div>
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}

    ...

</body>
```

---

Tip: restart `runserver` after adding a new templatetag file for it to be found.

Comment: If you could also show an example that defines a class that inherits ListView that the OP uses for the class view inheritance that has an inherited custom `get_context_data` method, this would make is so I don't need to post an answer

Comment: @ViaTech you can add your answer too. I would still recommend templatetags for this though. With inheritance, you'll either put this in ListView and I think some pages will miss the data because `base.html` could be used by other pages. Alternatively, you could add yet another class: BaseView (parent of ListView) or a mixin for it. I think that will make the code a bit messy.

Technically, `news` could also be defined via a middleware.

Comment: NameError: name register is not defined.

Comment: @nameless You are missing the import, etc.

```from django import template``` and 

```register = template.Library()```

Please read the doc here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/custom-template-tags/